# Query a table for Related Old Reports

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am back to this issue. Here is my table with some records:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
    [reportID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [caseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [carriedOver] [bit] NULL,
    [oldReportID] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[test] ([reportID], [caseID], [carriedOver], [oldReportID]) 
VALUES (304, 4, 1, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[test] ([reportID], [caseID], [carriedOver], [oldReportID]) 
VALUES (305, 4, 0, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[test] ([reportID], [caseID], [carriedOver], [oldReportID]) 
VALUES (306, 4, 1, 304)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[test] ([reportID], [caseID], [carriedOver], [oldReportID]) 
VALUES (309, 4, 1, 306)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[test] ([reportID], [caseID], [carriedOver], [oldReportID]) 
VALUES (311, 4, 0, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[test] ([reportID], [caseID], [carriedOver], [oldReportID]) 
VALUES (312, 4, 1, 309)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[test] ([reportID], [caseID], [carriedOver], [oldReportID]) 
VALUES (100, 1, 0, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[test] ([reportID], [caseID], [carriedOver], [oldReportID]) 
VALUES (418, 8, 0, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[test] ([reportID], [caseID], [carriedOver], [oldReportID]) 
VALUES (436, 8, 1, NULL)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[test] ([reportID], [caseID], [carriedOver], [oldReportID]) 
VALUES (438, 8, 0, 436)
GO
```

Desired output is as follows :

For CaseID = 4, I should get back ReportIDs : 304, 306, 309 and 312

For CaseID = 1, I should get back only ReportID : 100

For CaseID = 8, I should get back only ReportID : 418

It is basically getting a chain of carried reportIDs when the first report is carried over along with what it is carried into. If the first report is not carried over, then it should return only that report.

A suggested solution was:

```
declare @caseID int = 4
SELECT t.reportID
FROM dbo.test t
 WHERE ( exists ( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.test t1 WHERE t1.reportID = t.oldReportID and t1.caseID = @caseID ) or
         exists ( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.test t2 WHERE t2.oldReportID = t.reportID and t2.caseID = @caseID )  )
and caseID = @caseID
ORDER BY 1 asc
```

This works fine for CaseID=4, but it fails for CaseID=1 or CaseID=8.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please tag the question with the RDBMS that you are using: is this SQLServer, or something else?

Comment: @GMB it is MS SQL Server 2016.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind this requirement?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I will be moving a lot of data from one report to another if a given report is carried over into a new one. I can do this with 2 queries, but trying to do it all in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve it with the following query

```
    DECLARE @caseID INT = 4
    DECLARE @ftrptID INT = (Select MIN(reportID) from dbo.test where caseID=@caseID )
    if EXISTS(Select 1 from dbo.test where carriedOver=1 and reportID=@ftrptID)
    BEGIN
        SELECT t.reportID
        FROM dbo.test t
         WHERE ( exists ( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.test t1 WHERE t1.reportID = t.oldReportID and t1.caseID = @caseID ) or
                 exists ( SELECT 1 FROM dbo.test t2 WHERE t2.oldReportID = t.reportID and t2.caseID = @caseID )  )
        and caseID = @caseID
        ORDER BY 1 asc
    END
    ELSE

        SELECT t.reportID
        FROM dbo.test t
        where reportID=@ftrptID
```

Comment: Very Nice ! Thank you.